# Π Product properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to know why this product tends to this result: $\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{n-j}=2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$. I just know that I should get out of the Π: $2^{n}$ but I don't know why $\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{n-j}=2^{n^2} \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^j}$.
If someone can tell me how the term $2^{n^2}$ is out of the Π. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the resulting exponent of 2 is just the sum of the exponents, $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \; (n-j) = \sum_{k=n}^{1} \; k \; \; \; $

Comment: Since all terms in the product are exponents with base $2$, you can rewrite your product as $\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{n-j} = 2^{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-j)}$.  Now... what do you know about summations and triangle sums in particular.  Can you figure out $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}n-j$?

Comment: Write the product you will see... $(2^n/2^j)*(2^n/2^j)*\ldots*(2^n/2^j)$. In this product, you have $n$ terms, each term contains $2^n$. So you have: $(2^n*2^n*\ldots*2^n)*\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1/2^j)$.

Comment: @zdm what you wrote is a bit misleading since $j$ changes from term to term.  It would appear at first glance that you intended the same value of $j$ for each when that should not have been the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{n-j}&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{2^n}{2^j}\\&=\dfrac{2^n}{2^0}*\dfrac{2^n}{2^1}*\dfrac{2^n}{2^2}*\ldots*\dfrac{2^n}{2^{n-2}}*\dfrac{2^n}{2^{n-1}}\\&=\dfrac{ \overbrace{2^n*2^n*2^n*\ldots*2^n*2^n}^{\color{red}{n \text{ terms}}}}{2^0*2^1*2^2*\ldots*2^{n-2}*2^{n-1}}\\&=\dfrac{\overbrace{2^n*2^n*2^n*\ldots*2^n*2^n}^{\color{red}{n \text{ terms}}}}{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j}\\&=\dfrac{(2^n)^n}{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j}=\dfrac{2^{n^2}}{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Then, you solve the product like $2^{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j} = 2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ or is there a property?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could use the summation as you did.